# D-Editor with debugging

Tags: editor, d

i've been programming a while in D [(http://www.digitalmars.com/d/)](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/) now. I prefer it to Java because it is faster. However, i have not found an Editor that supports Code-Completion and Debugging (Step-Over, Step-Into, Breakpoints,...).

Do you have any suggestions?

P.S: gdb did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Descent](http://www.dsource.org/projects/descent), the Eclipse plugin, should support both (if you have a D supporting debugger installed). I have to admit I haven't tried it in a long time though, and when I did, debugging did *not* work, using gdb.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179/an-ide-for-d)

Personally I use Vim which currently provides neither completion nor debugging, although I know a completion engine was started once.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try the excellent [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) IDE. It has a very good support for D (it even automatically recognizes DMD and/or GDC D compilers).

Another alternative has already been mentioned above - Descent. I haven't used Descent because whenever I tried it I had problems and at some point I gave up (this does not mean it is bad, it means I am just lazy to figure out what problems were).

C::B uses GDB so I guess (not sure, did not try) you can use patched GDB to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux I use Eclipse (+Descent) or gEdit as IDE and use gdb as debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I use descent as well. I don't use it's debugger bit but that is because I'm editing on a windows desktop and building/running/debugging on a Linux server.

Comment: is programming without debugging really productive?

Comment: In some cases it actually can be better than with a debugger. For example trace log debugging rocks in cases where any place you put a breakpoint will get hit a few thousand times for each time you want it to get hit. To boot you can "run the code backwards"